# Hand of cards: Total value (Java)

Tags: java

I am currently working on a hand of cards class that uses enums that requires me to add methods that:

Add cards  into the hand

Calculate the total value of all the cards currently in the hand (so if there were 3 10's  in the hand then the total value would be 30)

The problem however is that I can't find out how to add up all the total while still implimenting the method within the hand class (as the task asks us to).

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Heres the code for my Suit enum

```
public enum Suit 
{    HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS, SPADES; }
```

Here is the code for my Rank enum.This one  has a few added methods including a getValue method

```
public enum Rank {   
    ONE(1),TWO(2),THREE(3),FOUR(4),FIVE(5), SIX (6), SEVEN(7), EIGHT(8), NINE(9), TEN(10), KING(10), QUEEN(10),
    JACK(10);

    private final int cardValue;

    private Rank ( int nDays) {
        cardValue = nDays;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return cardValue;
    }
}
```

This is the Card class that uses the Rank and Suit enums to print off the details (excuse the mess)

```
 public class Card {
     private Rank rank;
     private Suit suit;

     public Card (Rank theRank) {       
        this(theRank,Suit.HEARTS);
     }

     public Card (Rank theRank, Suit theSuit) {
        rank = theRank;         
        suit = theSuit;
     }

     public Rank getRank( )      { return rank; }
     public Suit getSuit ( )  { return suit; }

     public String toString ( ) { return ( rank + " of " + suit +"\n Value of card = " + rank.getValue() ); }

  }
```

And this is the Hand class that requires the addCard method and the totalValue method. I have done the addCard method and now need to do totalValue method)

```
 public class Hand {
 private Card theCards[ ];
 private Rank rank;
 private int numCards;    private int totalValue;
 private static final int max = 5;

 public Hand ( )
 {
  theCards = new Card [max];
  numCards = 0;
 }

 public void addCard( Card aCard )
 {
      if (numCards < max)
              theCards[numCards++] = aCard;
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Cannot add any more cards as hand is full");
      }
 }

 public void totalValue ()
     {
     int handValue = 0;


         for(Card C: theCards)
         {
             //get the rank values to appear then print them off
             //Add up all values of cards and display the total
        totalValue = handValue + C.getValue(); //This was just a test to see if calling up the value of card C would work

         }
         System.out.println("The total value of all the cards is: " + totalValue);
 }


 public String toString ( )
 {
    String s = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numCards; ++i)  {       s += "\n" + theCards[i];
    }
    return s;
                          }
```

As far as implimentation goes its just a case of creating card objects and adding them to the Hand object so I don't think I'll need to post that here. Thank you to anyone who can help me with my problem.

Comment: If this is homework, tag it as homework.

Comment: @Gevorg: scroll the code window to the right. :o

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the TEN, where's the TEN? :/

Comment: @Gevorg: um, it's in the code with king, queen, etc. Again, scroll the code window to the right to see it.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Yeah, I got it after your first comment, don't worry! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Card doesn't have a `getValue()` method but Rank does. So get the card's Rank via its `getRank()` method and then call `getValue()` on the rank returned.

Answer (score 2):

The value of a `Card` is available through its `rank` field. Right now you are trying to call `getValue()` directly on the `Card`, but there's no such method (yet).

Also, you'd normally `return` the total value of the hand from the `totalValue()` method, rather than simply printing it; this allows other code to actually use the value.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to figure out how to make it print without returning any nullexception errors. Basicly I simply converted the array into an arraylist as it was much more practical. Here is the final version of the Hand class.

```
 import java.util.*;
 public class Hand {

 private ArrayList<Card> theCards = new ArrayList<Card >() ;
 private static final int max = 5;

 public void addCard( Card aCard )
 {
      if (theCards.size() < max)
              theCards.add(aCard);
      else
      {
          System.out.println("Cannot add any more cards as hand is ull");
      }
 }
 public void totalValue() {
 int totalValue = 0;
 for (Card card : theCards) {
     totalValue += card.getRank().getValue();

     }
  System.out
     .println("The total value of all the cards is: " + totalValue);
 }

    public void outputAllCards ( )
 {
        System.out.println("Outputting all card etails\n========================");
        for (Card card : theCards)
        {
            System.out.println(card.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("========================");
  } }
```

I put in a println in order to print a message out when the totalValue method was called. I tried returning by turning the method into a string or int but this didn't work

Comment: It is ok to copy someone's else code or suggestions, but it isn't at least not to mention the contribution.

Answer (score -2):

The value is inside the rank. Does the rank object inside hand play any role (such as doubling value of the corresponding cards in the hand, you have to specify the game rules)? You just have to add up the rank values. I rewrote your code to leave out some unneccessary counters/vars. On the other side it is better to keep a list instead of an array if it can grow.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Hand {
    private final List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private Rank rank;
    private static final int MAX = 5;

    public void addCard(Card aCard) {
    if (cards.size() < MAX) {
        cards.add(aCard);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Cannot add any more cards as hand is full");
    }
    }

    public void totalValue() {
    int totalValue = 0;
    for (Card card : cards) {
        totalValue += card.getRank().getValue();

    }

    System.out
        .println("The total value of all the cards is: " + totalValue);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Card card : cards) {
        sb.append('\n').append(card.toString());
    }

    return sb.toString();
```

}
}

Comment: Shouldn't totalValue return something? As written it simply makes the calculation and then discards it which is somewhat misleading to the newbie. Héck, your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: Fernando is right. Netbeans compiles it but then it gives a nullexception error. Based on what Fernando said is there a way to do the calculation without discarding it?

Comment: @ThomasPooler: totalValue() should not have a println statement in it. Rather it should be defined to return an int, not void, and then at the end of the method, return totalValue. Then call this method when and where you need to calculate a hand's totalValue.

Comment: But he's not saying anything different then what we've already posted above. All he's done is post an incorrect example.

Comment: Yeah. This was the first thing that I did when testing the code. It will compile but throw a nullexception error. I'm a student so I think this an error that I'll come along quite a lot so is there anyone that can explain what this error means and what normally causes it to appear?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: totalValue() is rewritten for example. Of course it should return sth if this class was used elsewhere. Original example just output sth.